# Move Multiple Vim Windows In A Column Together

Tags: vim, neovim

I've had a lot of trouble figuring out window management in VIM. I know about commands like <kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd></kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> and friends (albeit I don't think I understand them well since they aren't helpful to me), and I've read numerous posts on rearranging windows, but no one gives me the info I need to help me answer my particular question. Maybe one of you vim window gurus can help?

Suppose I have a layout like this:

```
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
| A | C | E |
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
| B | D | F |
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
```

I want to swap entire columns, for example move A+B to the middle or to the right. If I use something like <kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd></kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> I now have this (assuming I was using window A)

```
+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |
|   | C | E |   |
|   |   |   |   |
| B |---+---| A |
|   |   |   |   |
|   | D | F |   |
|   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+
```

Definitely not what I want - especially since I have zero idea of how to join two windows into a column. At this point I usually just recreate my window layout and open the buffers I want in each window manually.

I also find it very difficult to grasp the concept of moving windows without seeing examples, so the manual isn't very helpful when it comes to trying to figure this out on my own.

How can I do what I am trying to achieve? Bonus points if you can tell me how to swap windows, e.g. A<=>D!

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/wesQ3/vim-windowswap. It seems to do what you want

Comment: vim-windowsnap is brilliant! It works for me. Add an answer and I'll select it @Steve!

Comment: I can't answer your other questions as the vim documentation is not non expert friendly :) SO Don't feel this is enough for an answer